# How to find representative numbers

Tags: math, statistics

I have a dataset, let's say it's [12,122,563,68,34,65,6,26,75,45,33,22,71,24,62,343,42,67,98,22,4,3,23,14], and suppose it represents the number of zombies on the street. I want to find three numbers a, b, c: below value a is labeled as relatively safe; below value b is labeled as a little dangerous; below value c is labeled as dangerous, and above c is labeled as very dangerous.

Mean:76.83

Standard Deviation:124.14

25th, 50th, 75th percentile = 22 38 68.75

how can I find a, b, c when the standard deviation of the dataset is so big? Please give me some advice!

Comment: How about `l = sorted([12, 122, 563, ..., 14]; a = l[len(l)//4]); b = l[len(l)//2]; c = l[(3*len(l))//4]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to identify the outliers in your data and either remove or replace them. The first step would be to get to know your data better. You can do that by:

1. Getting the statistical summary of the data
2. Visualize your data with histogram and boxplot

For your case you can see that 3,4,6 and 563, 122, 343 are the outliers. By just removing them you will get more sensible statistical summary of your data. Here's what you get:

```
Mean = 44.6
std = 25.1
```

Then you can use percentile to get your a, b, c. Additionally, you can look into Interquartile Range, Skewness or kurtosis for better understanding of outliers.